# Dynamically creating nested navigation menu item using Bootstrap and Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, navbar

What I want to achieve is dynamically creating a menu in bootstrap based on a json using angularjs.

**The json looks like this:**

```
 {
    "Page A":"page_A.html",
    "Page B":{
        "Page B1":"page_B/page_B1.html",
        "Page B2":"page_B/page_B2.html",
        "Page B3":{
            "Page B3-a":"page_B/page_B3/page_a.html",
            "Page B3-b":"page_B/page_B3/page_b.html"
        }
    },
    "Page C":"page_C.html"
}
```

where The object key is the name of the page and object value is the physical file location.

**The angular app.js look like this**

```
app.controller('navCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('data/menu.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.menus   = data;
    });
});
```

where menus is stores the json

**The HTML bootstarp look like this (Work in progress, doesn't work)**

```
<div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
       <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
                <li ng-repeat="(key,value) in menus">
                     <a href="../{{value}}"><i class="dropdown-toggle"  data-toggle="dropdown"></i> {{key}} </a>
                 </li>
             </ul>
       </div>
</div>
```

My Question:

- How can I create **nested** navbar item based on the json?
- Is there any other **Angularjs directive** that can do better in terms of recursion and nested beside **ng-repeat**?
- Should I change my **json convention** to make it easier? If so, How?

I am new to both Angularjs and Bootstrap. Please be gentle.

Answer (score 0):

Object.keys(data) just show like this : 
["Page A", "Page B", "Page C"]

loop again :)

Comment: Thanks, the reason that I use objects.keys is because the ng-repeat automatically sort the sequence of the json objects.